# How do I build Android project using a newer version of gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

I have an Android project built using gradle 1.10. I would like to build it using gradle 2.4. There are few threads where some changes are suggested which should do the job. Some users have said these changes have worked and some have not worked.

I would like to know if there is a way I can copy certain number of files and build the whole thing from scratch using Gradle 2.4?

Thanks.

It was built using Android Studio 0.5.1.

Here is Project level build.gradel:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Here is the module level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 19
        versionName "19.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: You should post your build.gradle

Comment: Posted both the build.gradle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the current Android Studio 1.3 you should use this top-level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

The `module/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion XX
    buildToolsVersion "XX.X.X"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion XX
        versionCode 19
        versionName "19.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX.X.X'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:XX.X.X'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Pay attention to use gradle 2.4 and change the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```